# MySql to IIF (PHP)

Tags: php, quickbooks

My Client use Quickbooks App and I need to import data from quickbook to PHP array so that I can add to database .

Here is the IIF File

[image]

Here is my database structure

[image]

I found this wonderful program http://php-quickbooks-iif-viewer-or-converter.soft112.com/download.html and manage to read the data and also store it.

[image]

```
    <?php
        $out="";
        $i=1;
            $data = file_get_contents("customers.IIF");
            $lines = split("\n", $data);
            $customers = array();
            $j = 1;

            foreach ($lines as $line) 
            {
                $endtag = strpos($line, "\t");
                $tag = substr($line, 0, $endtag);

                if ($tag=="!CUST") 
                {
                    $line = str_replace("\"", "", $line);
                    $arline = explode("\t", $line);

                    echo print_r($arline);
                    echo "<br><br>";
                } 
                elseif ($tag=="CUST") 
                {
                    $line = str_replace("\"", "", $line);
                    $arline = explode("\t", $line);

                    $name = explode(" ", $arline[19]);
                    if ( count($name) == 2 ) 
                    {
                        $fname = $name[0];
                        $lname = "'" . $name[1] . "'";
                    } 
                    else 
                    {
                        $fname = $arline[19];
                        $lname = 'NULL';
                    }

                    $i++; $j++;
                    $cli = "INSERT INTO 'bamboo_clients' ('id', 'name', 'address1', 'address2', 'city', 'province', 'country', 'postal_code', 'website', 'tax_status', 'client_notes') VALUES\n"
                         . "($i, '$arline[1]', '$arline[5]', '', '$arline[6]', '$arline[7]', 'USA', '$arline[8]', NULL, 1, NULL);\n\n";

                    $con = "INSERT INTO 'bamboo_clientcontacts' ('id', 'client_id', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'title', 'email', 'phone', 'password', 'access_level', 'supervisor', 'last_login', 'password_reset') VALUES\n"
                         . "($j, $i, '$fname', $lname, NULL, '$arline[17]', '$arline[14]', NULL, 0, NULL, NULL, NULL);\n\n";

                    $out .= $cli . $con;

                    print_r($arline);


                    // Create connection
                    $connection=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","cakephp");

                    // Check connection
                    if (mysqli_connect_errno())
                    {
                        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
                    }

                    $query="INSERT INTO customers 
                            (country,company,user_id     ,mobile       ,        email,        title,cutomer_name)
                        VALUES
                            ('$arline[5]','$arline[1]','$arline[2]','$arline[14]','$arline[17]','$arline[28]','$arline[18]');";


                    print_r($query);
                    mysqli_query($connection,$query);


                    //echo $cli;
                    //echo $con;
                }
            }
            file_put_contents("bambooinvoice-customers.sql", $out);
        ?>
```

Above is my modifed code to read IIF. Now I need to export to IIF. Is there anyway to achieve ? I only need to export customers list .

Answer (score 0):

The IIF file format has been *deprecated* by Intuit for years and years and years now. It is known to corrupt QuickBooks company files and be very limited in what it can do. *You should not be using IIF imports/exports*.

You should instead use the QuickBooks SDK. The easiest way to go is to start with the [QuickBooks PHP DevKit](https://github.com/consolibyte/quickbooks-php) (disclaimer: I'm the author).

- Download the [QuickBooks PHP DevKit](https://github.com/consolibyte/quickbooks-php) from GitHub
- Follow the [Quick start guide for the Web Connector and PHP](http://www.consolibyte.com/docs/index.php/PHP_DevKit_for_QuickBooks_-_Quick-Start)

It should take you all of about an hour to get a working, automate-able export of customers to QuickBooks if you follow that.

Comment: Thanks Keith Palmer .let me try and get back to you asap.

Comment: Keith Palmar , my quickbook is a window app and client refused to do upgrades. He is an old guy. I want to link with Cakephp(online) and Quickbook(offline windows app) . Is that still possible ?

Comment: Yes - the links I posted above will work fine with CakePHP and the Windows version of QuickBooks.

Comment: The IIF format still seems to be the best option and most recommended option for Quickbooks Desktop version..

Answer (score 0):

I built a view on the SQL server of the data in the right order, then had a php cli script build a text file for me, with the .iif extension.  The php wrote out the headers for the iif, with the requisite tab separations, and then the data came out of the query, and instead of a CSV format, it shoved a tab into the output as the column separator. No SDK needed.

Answer (score -1):

The answer is without a third party plugin or via developing your own plugin there is only the manual way for exporting IIF files from quickbooks. 
(https://quickbooks.intuit.com/community/Reports-and-accounting/Export-or-import-Intuit-Interchange-Format-IIF-files/m-p/203229)

Since your target is PHP, then as Palmer mentioned using the webconnect and the PHP DevKit would probably be what you are looking for.

However Mr. Palmer is not correct when implying the IIF is not approved by QB, infact they have continued to expand the use of IIF. However IIF does not seem to be the tool your actually looking to use.